# JavaScript Prototypical Inheritance

Tags: javascript

I've some code like

```
function Vehicle(){
  this.isMovable = true;
}
Vehicle.prototype = {
  hasTyres:function(){ return true;},
  needsFuel:true
};

var Car  = function(){
  Vehicle.call(this);
  this.type = "Car";
};
```

Now

It works even if I create prototype like this

```
Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);
```

or

```
Car.prototype = Vehicle.prototype;
```

What is the difference ?

I was under the impression that

```
Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle);
```

will cause Car to inherit from vehicle ,but it's not.

Can anyone explain what's happening inside Object.create method

Thanks,
SRK

Comment: If you want to know what `Object.create` does, have a look at the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: A car is a vehicle but a vehicle is not necessarily a car (can be a bus). So you can't set their prototypes to be equal to each other. More on prototype here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);`

This one creates an object whose prototype is `Vehicle.prototype`. In this object, you put your shared methods for `Car` instances while "inheriting" from `Vehicle`. This is the right way to go.

```
Car instance -> Car prototype -> Vehicle prototype
```

---

`Car.prototype = Vehicle.prototype;`

This one uses the same prototype for `Vehicle` to `Car`. This means that you'll be clobbering the same object for both classes. Adding to `Car.prototype` would mean also adding it to `Vehicle.prototype`, which you don't want.

```
Car instance -> Car prototype (which is also Vehicle prototype)
```

---

`Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle);`, `Car.prototype` is an object whose prototype is `Vehicle`, a function. You don't want this either.

```
Car instance -> Car prototype -> Vehicle function
```

Answer (score 1):

`Vehicle` is a function.  Calling `Object.create(Vehicle);` will create an object whose prototype is that function.
That's not what you want.

Writing `Car.prototype = Vehicle.prototype;` will use the same `prototype` object for both classes, making it impossible to add a function to the derived class only.

For more details, see [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/).